# Finding last items of a multi-column listview

Tags: vba, excel

I have a multi-column listview that a colleague created in a useform. It gets populated once the useform opens. I want to find the items in the last row of the populated listview. For example:

```
header1   header2   header3
 11         12        13
 21         22        23
 31         32        33
```

I want a line (or a few lines) to store `31`, `32`, and `33` in separate variables.

My ListView is named `lsvLots`. I am capable of storing `31` in the String `strProduct` with the following:

```
 strProduct = lsvLots.ListItems.Item(lsvLots.ListItems.Count)
```

HoweverI can only returns the last item of the first column that way. How can I access the other columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line in the list is determined by the `ListCount` and can be referenced as follows:

```
UserForm1.lsvLots.List(UserForm1.lsvLots.ListCount - 1, 0)
```

Note, that the `ListCount` will be 1 if there is one row in the ListBox. Yet, the index to reference this (first & last row) starts with 0 and not with 1. Therefore, you have to subtract 1 from the `ListCount` to convert it to an index (starting with 0).

The 0 at the end means, that you want to get the first column from that row. Once again, the columns are 0 for the first column, 1 for the second column, 2 for the third column, etc.

In short, to get all the items from the last row you should use:

```
strProduct1 = UserForm1.lsvLots.List(UserForm1.lsvLots.ListCount - 1, 0)
strProduct2 = UserForm1.lsvLots.List(UserForm1.lsvLots.ListCount - 1, 1)
strProduct3 = UserForm1.lsvLots.List(UserForm1.lsvLots.ListCount - 1, 2)
```

OR (to be neater):

```
With UserForm1.lsvLots
    strProduct1 = .List(.ListCount - 1, 0)
    strProduct2 = .List(.ListCount - 1, 1)
    strProduct3 = .List(.ListCount - 1, 2)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
strProduct = lsvLots.ListItems(lsvLots.ListItems.Count).SubItems(1)
```